# Different outputs in different SAS versions in GARCH model under PROC AUTOREG

Tags: sas, autoregressive-models

Following is my SAS program to build GARCH model using PROC AUTOREG:

```
proc autoreg data=DATASET;
model Y= X1 X2
/method=ml nlag=12 garch=(p=1,q=1, type=nelson, startup=MSE) maxiter=500 dwprob OPTMETHOD=QN;
run;
```

I ran this same program using same database in 2 different versions of SAS:

1) Base SAS

2) ETS SAS;

Both are giving different GARCH estimates, although AUTOREG estimates are same.
Please help why it is so and how to get same outputs?

Comment: Base SAS would require ETS module to run an autoreg model. You must be using different versions of SAS that have different default settings. If you provide the version of SAS perhaps we can help more.

Comment: Base SAS does not inherently run autoregressive models. SAS/ETS is the way to run those models. It sounds like you have two different versions of SAS/ETS on each.

Run `proc product_status` from each version of SAS and post the results.